# Is there a way to create docker image containing docker and java

Tags: java, linux, docker, docker-container, docker-image

I want to create a Docker image with Java and Docker installed on it. The idea is that the eventual docker container should be able to create Docker images. My Java application executes commands like `docker build -t my-image .`.

That is why I need Docker installed in my Docker container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to creating Dockerfile with maven jdk and docker installed for jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184921/how-to-creating-dockerfile-with-maven-jdk-and-docker-installed-for-jenkins-pipel)

Comment: Remember that the ability to run any `docker` command at all comes with the ability to root the entire host; think carefully about whether you need this much power just to build an image.  The question @HansKilian refers to mentions a CI environment, and it's possible the CI system will know how to launch containers with build tools and then build images on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I solved the same issue writing the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8

USER root

# Install docker CLI for docker images generation inside the container itself

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz | tar xvz -C /tmp/ && mv /tmp/docker/docker /usr/bin/docker

# Customize here your container with your instructions...
```

Of course, you can change the `FROM` image as per you needs.